# How to pass the user login information to the React application running on Liferay 7.2?

Tags: reactjs, liferay

We have a separate application built using React. This application is deployed as a widget on the Liferay server. We are creating the users in the Liferay platform. How can we pass the user information to the React application?

thanks

Comment: Please observe https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824

Comment: On very little information provided in the question - best suggestion would be use available "Liferay" Object of javascript.